# sed replace dots on each lines with patern

Tags: bash, sed

i need help for replacing dots on a spesific patern given , 
EX:

```
[my title="my.name part 02"][A]
[A][A2 title="Backup"][my data="http://domain/my.name.jpg"][/A2][/A][/A2]
[A][A2 title="Backup"][my data="http://domain/my.name2.jpg"][/A2][/A]

[my title="my.name part 03"][A]
[A][A2 title="Backup"][my data="http://domain/my.name3.jpg"][/A2][/A][/A2]
[A][A2 title="Backup"][my data="http://domain/my.name4.jpg"][/A2][/A]

[my title="my.name part 04"][A]
[A][A2 title="Backup"][my data="http://domain/my.name5.jpg"][/A2][/A][/A2]
[A][A2 title="Backup"][my data="http://domain/my.name6.jpg"][/A2][/A]
```

so im trying to remove dots from my.name on each lines , i've tried with basic sed command for replace but all http link also got replaced.

```
sed -i -e 's/my.name/my name/g' file
```

if i used that sed command above it will break down my images link.

i really appriciated if someone would help me solved this.

thank you so much.

*Edited

Comment: `sed 's/my\.name/my name/' file` Add all the switches you need to `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -ri 's:(^\[my title.*)[.](.*$):\1 \2:' filename
```

Split the line beginning with "[my title" into two sections separated by "." and then refer to them as \1 and \2 in the translated sed expression.

Comment: almost work bro , but need slightly change , the result is [my title="myname not [my title="my name

Comment: It should be "myname" and not "my name". \1\2 will concatenate the string after the "." with the string before with no spaces. Worked fine when I tested.

Comment: Apologies, I misread you question. I have amended the solution to add a space between \1 and \2

Comment: Thank You Raman Sailopa its working now , appriciate a lot for your help!